# setting attribute on select not persisting

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have a select input where I'm setting the multiple attribute via jQuery. I then have a console.log confirming that code functions correctly, then if i console.log again its no longer there. Any suggestions?

`thisQuestionHTML` is just a block of HTML code (2 divs wrapped around a select statement I'm casting as a jQuery object.

```
line 1: $(thisQuestionHTML).find('.answerValue').attr('multiple','multiple');
line 2: console.log($(thisQuestionHTML).find('.answerValue').attr('multiple','multiple'));
line 3: console.log($(thisQuestionHTML));
```

Line 1 : this is the non-debug code I'm expecting to actually set it

Line 2: this debug code is confirming its being set. It returns the select statement complete with the `multiple="multiple"`

```
<select class=​"answerValue" data-questionid=​"a0NJ0000008ZwjOMAS" multiple=​"multiple">​</select>​
```

Line 3: this debug code returns the select statement **without** the `multiple` attribute.

```
<div class=​"control-group">​
    <span class=​"control-label">​MS picklist question​</span>​
    <div class=​"controls">​
        <select class=​"answerValue" data-questionid=​"a0NJ0000008ZwjOMAS">​</select>​
    </div>​
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new jQuery object on each of the three lines because `thisQuestionHTML` is just a HTML string. jQuery isn't updating the string, `thisQuestionHTML` is never changed.

> Line 2: this debug code is confirming its being set.

This^ is not true, you are setting the value once again (note the two arguments to `attr()`).

Store a reference to the object instead of creating new each time:

```
var obj = $(thisQuestionHTML);
obj.find('.answerValue').attr('multiple','multiple');
console.log(obj); // contains updated select
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was aware it wasnt really confirming the previous line more just confirming the logic of line1 was functioning correctly. This worked. I also had to add `.end()` to be able to reassign `obj.html()` to my HTML string, also had to use `slice()` to remove the closing tags it added. not very pretty.

Answer (score 0):

use `filter()`

```
$(thisQuestionHTML).filter ('.controls .answerValue').attr('multiple','multiple');
```